# You do not have permission to call ScriptApp.getProjectTriggers. Required permissions: https://www.googleapis.com/auth/script.scriptapp

Tags: google-apps-script, triggers, scopes

I get this error, even though I added this scope to my apps-script project manifest.

What else is missing?

```
You do not have permission to call ScriptApp.getProjectTriggers. Required permissions: https://www.googleapis.com/auth/script.scriptapp
```

[image]

Comment: Have you tried to add that scope to your manifest

Comment: By any chance, are you using a custom function called 'onOpen' in your code?

Comment: More general are you using any simple trigger to call you code?  Simple triggers cannot do operations that require permission.

Comment: @Cooper `More general are you using any simple trigger to call you code? Simple triggers cannot do operations that require permission.` I think this is the problem, can you post this as an answer + the doc your rely on?

Comment: Just look up simple triggers in the documentation it's in the guides section

Comment: @Cooper also, I have ads-script that write to a spreadsheet but doesn't trigger a simple or a custom onEdit trigger. Only when I edit the spreasdheet myself this is triggered. Why?

Comment: Yes onEdit triggers are only generated by user edits.  They are not created by other scripts or forumulas.  You can get an onChange type=other trigger with changes like a importRange writing to a sheet but the event object is pretty useless in that case.

Comment: @Cooper Thanks, but onChange wasn't triggered as well when ads-script write to the spreadsheet. Why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As simple triggers fire automatically, without asking the user for authorization, they are subject to several restrictions that are explained in the "Restrictions" section of the following Developers Center page called "Simple Triggers" [1].

It's worth considering if any of these restrictions have an impact on your application.

[1] https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers#restrictions

Comment: I have an ads-script that writes to a spreadsheet but doesn't trigger a simple or a custom onChange. Why?

Comment: I don't think that there is a simple onChange event.  They are only installable